# Why is wp-login redirecting to the home page when I use this function?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, conditional-tags

I'm perplexed; I can't see where I'm going wrong with this code. It should redirect any subscriber-level users back to the site home page if they try to access anything within /wp-admin - but *not* if they try to go to /wp-login.php :

```
// REDIRECT ALL 'SUBSCRIBER' USERS TO SITE HOME PAGE IF THEY TRY TO ACCESS WP-ADMIN
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
function blockusers_init() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit' ) && is_admin() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

I tried using the role instead of capability (`'subscriber'` instead of `'edit'`), and that worked when I was on a single-site installation of WordPress - but this theme is now being used in a multisite/subfolder installation and for some reason the role doesn't work. Using the code above, anytime a subscriber goes to either /wp-admin or /wp-login.php they get redirected to the home page.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I added this my functions file in a vanilla WP install, and it doesn't redirect me when I hit wp-login. Have you tried disabling all plugins? Also, "edit" isn't a capability, unless it's custom to your install: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: thank you! I must be going blind. Sadly it still doesn't work in multisite, but at least that's one potential issue eliminated. I did try disabling all plugins and that didn't have any effect.

Comment: My bad--I didn't try it on a multisite install.

Answer (score 3):

So, first off, if you want to block access to `wp-admin`, why hook into something that fires on every page load?  Hook into `admin_init` instead.

And, as @MattSmath mentioned, edit isn't a capability.  `edit_posts` is.  Also, `admin_init` only fires on admin pages, so you can remove `is_admin()` from your check.

Your revised function:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse51831_init');
function wpse51831_init()
{
    if(!current_user_can('edit_posts')) 
    {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit();
    }
}
```

Bonus: You're probably not going to want to show your `subscriber` level users the WordPress admin bar (which links them back to `wp-admin`).  This will hide it:

```
<?php
add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'wpse51831_hide_admin_bar');
/*
 * hide the admin bar for `subscribers`
 *
 * @uses current_user_can
 * @return boolean
 */
function wpse51831_hide_admin_bar($bool)
{
    if(!current_user_can('edit_posts'))
    {
        $bool = false;
    }
    return $bool;
}
```

Comment: The "admin" bar is not an admin bar in 3.4, it's a generic toolbar that, in many cases, is integrated into the theme.  +1 for the code to fix the admin, -1 for hiding a somewhat essential core feature.

Comment: Thank you for both these! Man do I feel dumb for not seeing the edit_posts thing. Unfortunately though even with the new code, it's still not working. /wp-admin redirects correctly, but wp-login.php also redirects. Maybe it's a multisite thing? Because it *does* work on a single-install of WP with the same plugins enabled.

Comment: Also thanks for the hiding admin bar filter, I actually already had that working. @EAMann, in my case I am using the login system only to show/hide certain content, and I really don't want any subscribers to see any part of the dashboard or WP functionality. So hiding the bar seems appropriate.